# WebClient TimeOut Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, timeout, webclient

I would like to run a task during the waiting of a web request. If the task finishes before the request can return a response, then I would display a message "The server is taking too long". I'm using a `WebClient` object, how can I manage the time out?

```
public Class Result
{
   protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
   {
      if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("critere", out sCritere))
      {
         try
         {
            _datamanager = new DataManager();
            _datamanager.m_evt_Client_DownloadStringCompleted += OnDownloadStringCompleted;
            _datamanager.DownloadXmlData(DataManager.URL_RECHERCHE, sCritere);

            //HERE I NEED TO RUN A TIMER If the response is too long i would display a message                          

          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
             MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Erreur", MessageBoxButton.OK);
             NavigationService.GoBack();
             NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
          }
       }
    }
  }

public Class DataManager
{
   public void DownloadXmlData(string uri, string critere = "")
   {
      try
      {   
         WebClient client = new WebClient();
         client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
         client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserSaved, PasswordSaved, domain);
         client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri + critere));
       }
       catch(WebException )
       {
          throw new WebException(MyExceptionsMessages.Webexception) ;
       }
       catch (Exception )
       {
          throw new UnknowException(MyExceptionsMessages.UnknownError);
       }
    }

   public void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   {
      //raise Downloadstringcompleted event if error==null
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BackgroundWorker..

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.DoWork += (s, e) =>
{
    // your task to do while webclient is downloading
};
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (s, e) =>
{
    // check whether DownloadStringCompleted is fired or not
    // if not, cancel the WebClient's asynchronous call and show your message.
    client.CancelAsync();
    MessageBox.Show("message");
}

client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: i found this ...maybe i should use Task...Looks easier and better...[Task VS BGW](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-4.html)